# How to use a marginfigure environment inside a tcolorbox environment?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, sidenotes

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
A test
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%[!h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

When I run the above code, I get some errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.15 \end{marginfigure}
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@marbox
l.15 \end{marginfigure}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If `marginfigure` is using `\marginpar` then it cannot escape the `tcolorbox` so you cannot do this.

Comment: Isn't there really any other way to do this?

Comment: It would be possible to use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package inside a `tcolorbox`, if this is an option.

Comment: @Sisabe this is one of the LaTeX limitations. Certain constructions cannot be used inside other constructions. The solution Thomas mention might be better as it can usually come out of boxes. But it does not automatically move if it gets too close to another margin thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just the other way, box in marginfigure:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=240mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=560pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
A test

\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%[!h]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{marginfigure}


\end{document}
```